# Запрос cURL'ом на сервер с просроченным сертификатом

Tags: php, curl, tls

Необходимо сделать запрос на сервер с просроченным сертификатом. Поддерживаются протокол `tls v1.1` и выше.

```
try {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen("curl_debug.log", "w+"));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    if ($response === false) {
        die("cURL error #" . curl_errno($curl) . ": " . curl_error($curl));
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Exception: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
curl_close($curl);
print_r($response);
```

На экран выводится:

> cURL error #35: SSL connect error

В `curl_debug.log` следующее:

```
* About to connect() to sometest.ru port 443 (#0)
*   Trying xx.xx.xxx.xxx... * connected
* Connected to sometest.ru (xx.xx.xxx.xxx) port 443 (#0)
* NSS error -5961
* Closing connection #0
* SSL connect error
```

При этом в консоли с параметром `-k` все отлично работает:

```
[user@server ~]$ curl --tlsv1.1 -v -k https://sometest.ru/
* About to connect() to sometest.ru port 443 (#0)
*   Trying xx.xx.xxx.xxx... connected
* Connected to sometest.ru (xx.xx.xxx.xxx) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* warning: ignoring value of ssl.verifyhost
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* SSL connection using TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
* Server certificate:
*       subject: Blah-blah-blah
*       start date: Дек 18 00:00:00 2014 GMT
*       expire date: Дек 18 23:59:59 2015 GMT
*       common name: sometest.ru
*       issuer: Blah-blah-blah
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: sometest.ru
> Accept: */ *
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.8.0
< Date: Mon, 21 Dec 2015 11:09:04 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host sometest.ru left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Так как среда, к которой пытаюсь обратиться, тестовая, в ближайшее время сертификат обновлять не будут. Не подскажите, как обойти проверку сертификата, и почему не работают параметры `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` и `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`?

**UPD** Версия `cURL`:

```
[user@server ~]$ curl --version
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

Comment: а значение `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` разве валидное? там же вроде только 1 и 2 может быть, а у вас он 0 равен

Comment: @BOPOH, в оф доке следующее: "When the verify value is 0, the connection succeeds regardless of the names in the certificate."

Comment: @BOPOH, долго думал, почему после собаки твое имя не высвечивается =)

Comment: В [доках](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php) про значение 0 ничего не сказано, вы же на php пишите, значит их доки и надо смотреть, они могут как угодно переопределить поведение curl'а. И, кстати, а CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER пробовали в false, а не 0 установить?

Comment: @BOPOH, пробовал. Также пробовал и без этого параметра.

Comment: адрес указали бы, куда попасть не может, чтобы именно на этом сайте смотреть

Comment: @BOPOH, к сожалению, в целях безопасности не могу его озвучить. Думаешь, проблема в сертификате? Тогда почему с терминала могу подключится?